# Cannot access props.navigation.state variables

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I got undefined errors when I try to saving props.navigation.state variables into state and using them on components

```
  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.setState({
      services: this.props.navigation.state.params.data.vendor_types_and_services,
      loading: false
    })
  }
```

then when I display the data it crash with error

```
  {!loading &&  <Text>{services.length}</Text>}
```

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'services.length')

When using the regular expression `this.props.navigation.state.params.data.vendor_types_and_services` it works just fine, I am not sure where is the problem, this is a different route on appNavigator, what's the alternative to `componentWillReceiveProps` or `componentWillMount`?

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```js
{!loading &&  <Text>{services.length}</Text>}
```

With

```js
{!loading && this.state.services !== null &&  <Text>{this.state.services.length}</Text>}
```

And make sure you have defined this state variable into constructor like this :

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    services: null,
    loading: true
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try destructuring and debug with a `console.log()`

```js
const { params } = props.navigation.state;
```

can you show how you receive these props from another component?

Comment: props are received when creating the component, if it is created as undefined, and at some other time you receive an update to the props and your component is already mounted, your props will not be updated

Comment: I am sending data as props with react router ```navigate('Studio', { data: item })```